# Fortify Scan raising vulnerabilities for d3 v3.5.17

Tags: javascript, security, d3.js, fortify

We have a application which is raising vulnerabilities when passing via fortify scan

Files - d3.min.js - verison 3.5.17

[D3 version link](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/blob/master/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js)  - Please check line number 9545

```
function d3_html(request) {
    var range = d3_document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(d3_document.body);
    return range.createContextualFragment(request.responseText);
  }
```

The above function is giving vulnerabilities:
1. "Read request.responseText" is one of them
2. "createContextualFragment()" points to other one

I tried to copy the file and keep it in my project folder instead of node_modules and manipulated the code inside the function like below but no luck(i was not 100% sure of the code change)

```
function d3_html(request) {
    var range = d3_document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(d3_document.body);

    var scrubbedText = (request && request.responseText) ? request.responseText : "";
    var contextFragment = range.createContextualFragment(scrubbedText)
    return contextFragment;
  }
```

Please help me out if someone has faced the same issue or knows the resolution

Comment: any luck ? was hoping you will find some solution :)